# Sort compare function weird behavior

Tags: c++, sorting

The function below is my compare function. While comparing directly two characters successfully assorts the array, using the std::string compare function doesn't.

```
int compare (student a, student b) {
  return a.name.compare(b.name);
  return a.name[0] < b.name[0];
}
```

The call

```
sort(data.begin(), data.end(), compare);
```

Where data is defined as `vector <student> data;`

Have you got any ideas why is it that std::compare doesn't sort it?

PS: std::compare results in inverting the positions, e.g. alan, richard, byron, sarah -> sarah, byron, richard, alan.

Comment: This isn't particularly clear.  Can you add some concrete test code (i.e. a 10-line program that we could compile and run, maybe in http://ideone.com) that demonstrates what isn't working?

Comment: Anyone else remotely interested in the type decl of `student` and its members? (and note: your second return is pointless).

Comment: eeemmm., am I the only one seeing the 2 return statements?

Comment: @DanC for the testing purposes, I always comment out one of them.

Comment: Why you did not try "return a.name < b.name;" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[std::string::compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) returns an `int` which you are meant to compare to `0` to give an actual sort order. For example, to check if `a.name` is less than `b.name` (according to the ordering given by `compare`) you would write:

```
return a.name.compare(b.name) < 0;
```

The way that you have currently written it will return `true` for any unequal strings, which is not a valid [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering), as required for [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

There is no good reason to use `compare` here at all, as [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) has an [operator<](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) that gives an equivalent ordering of the two strings:

```
return a.name < b.name;
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a read through the [std::sort reference at cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort); it clearly explains that the comparison function should return a `bool` which indicates the first argument is less than the second.

In this case, you would call it like this:

```
std::sort(data.begin(), data.end(), [](student const& a, student const& b) {
    return a.name < b.name;
})
```

So, what's happening in your code? If the `name`s are equal, `compare` returns 0, which is cast to `false`. Otherwise, you will get a non-zero integer, which will be cast to `true`. Since the sorting algorithm in `std::sort` isn't specified absolutely, we can't say why you are getting a certain order precisely, but essentially, `std::sort` is `std::swap`ing objects (pseudo) randomly.

So, should you define a `compare` function? IMHO, no. It is quite easily to define for some basic types, but as far as I can tell, it doesn't really appear in any algorithms. It is a C-ism, and unfortunately, C++ kept it. If appropriate, define a *strict weak ordering* using `operator<` instead, or just define comparators when needed.

Answer (score 1):

sort expects its comparator to behave like operator<, whereas std::string::compare behaves as described [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/).

Answer (score 1):

You're returning an `int` which `std::sort` sees as either "same" or "not same". You should be returning this:

```
return a.name.compare(b.name) < 0;
```

And change the return type to `bool`

However, have you considered this instead:

```
class student
{
public:
   ... members ...

   bool operator <(const student& s) const
   {
       return name < s.name;
   }

private:
   std::string name;
};
```

And get rid of the custom comparator you're trying to fabricate *entirely*. With this you can then sort a collection of students using just `std::sort(students.begin(), students.end())`, since the default comparator, `std::less<YourType>`, will invoke your operator when doing comparisons while sorting.

Comment: Or a simple `a.name < b.name`

Comment: @SethCarnegie Yeah, yeah, he seems fixed on using that function. dunno why. Why not just not use a comparator *at all*. std::less<> does exactly what you have.

Comment: Only if `student` has an `operator<`.

Comment: @SethCarnegie *Exactly* which is what should *really* be defined in the first place.

Comment: @WhozCraig I didn't expect the < operator to be overloaded in the string class.

Comment: @SethCarnegie I'd better save the < operator for students' grades.

Comment: @Grant it certainly is. that class is Rich with a capital R. However, if you have different sorting needs of the same collection as the situation warrants, then using custom comparison functors or functions is the way to go.